# Unchangeable EXIF datas

Tags: jpeg, exif

Do you know if there are unchangeable EXIF datas ?

In my case i want to know the real date of creation of a jpeg image. So I thought the EXIF's datas was the best way but I realized that with a software like XnView you can change it. So there is any way i can now the real date of the creation of an image ?

In another hand, is it possible to know if a EXIF datas has been modified ?

Thx fo all,

And sorry for my bad english

Have a good day !

:)

Answer (score 0):

In principle, it is not possible to be sure the data hasn't been edited, although it may take a great deal of skill to do so indetectably. Some of the major camera makers (Canon and Nikon, possibly others) offer an "image authentication" feature in their pro model cameras which is designed to make it impossible to modify the image after it has been taken. They do this for the benefit of people doing legal work - evidence shots and the like. To use this, you have to switch it on (via the camera settings) before you take the picture. Even with these though, it is still possible to alter the data: both the Canon and Nikon authentication systems have been cracked (presumably with considerable difficulty).

As for normal pictures, yes, these are very easy to alter. However many (most?) programs which can edit EXIF data leave their own signs. For example, Adobe Photoshop always adds its own name somewhere in the EXIF, apparently whether you want it to or not. You can see this with many different EXIF viewers, especially with the more advanced ones like PhotoME. (Which, sadly, is no longer maintained.)

Short answer: yes, it is always possible to exit EXIF, and almost always possible to do it indetectably, but it may requite the right tools and quite a lot of skill. You can't ever be certain it has not been done.